# Is there an Interface Hall of Shame and Fame for web design?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, desktop-application

There's the [Interface Hall of Shame](http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/mshame.htm) and also the [Interface Hall of Fame](http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/mfame.htm) for desktop UI design. The company that created the site doesn't exist since quite a time. Their site has been archived by another company 23 years ago. Nevertheless it's still funny to browse through it and see what people do just because it can be done.

And if I may be a bit immodest: There's a comment from me on the Lotus Notes feedback page since then. (For the younger: No, that's not a sports car for bankers or musicians.)

Is there something comparable for web design?

Nothing is so useless that it cannot at least serve as a bad example.

Comment: The closest I can get here is the concept of "Dark Patterns" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern - The guy who coined the term also wrote a book about them which has examples and explains the mechanics/psychology employed. This could be because the web is constantly changing along with our understanding of what 'Good' and 'Bad' are for users.

Comment: @RouxMartin it is now known as Deceptive Patterns (https://www.deceptive.design/)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Hall of Fame, but the Deceptive patterns website does have a [Hall of Shame](https://www.deceptive.design/hall-of-shame/all). You should note that sometimes what is referred to as 'dark' or 'deceptive' patterns are actually just poor UX/UI design without malicious intent, but often people don't take the time to make the distinction.

There are lots of websites that list or present awards for good web design, such as the [Webby Awards](https://www.webbyawards.com/) or [Awwwards](https://www.awwwards.com/) that have their own criteria and theme when it comes to good design.

Answer (score 1):

Where interesting question.
I guess now you can only find the archived sites on the Internet space.
Like "Web Pages That Suck" ([www.webpagesthatsuck.com](http://www.webpagesthatsuck.com)) site which showcased examples of poor web design.
Nowadays all these resources migrate to social media and community sites ([www.reddit.com/r/crappydesign](http://www.reddit.com/r/crappydesign)).
Most of them you can find in Artiles of popular magazines ([www.smashingmagazine.com](http://www.smashingmagazine.com)), or like the case studies of famous companies ([www.nngroup.com](http://www.nngroup.com))